# GIT XCODE4 - Authentication Error

Tags: git, xcode4

I am getting authentication error when tryinh to conect to the remote repository. I am pretty sure my username and password is correct. I get the error and the XCODE hangs. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Give more details on the url you are using etc.

Comment: https and also if i check my key using edit key i found that my email part is missing. I tried to add it a couple of times. still the email id is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the config, can you try mentioning the username and password along with the URL, if you have not done already

```
 https://username:password@github.com/...
```

Comment: I added the username and token key which i missed and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What authentication are you using? Login/pass? SSH key?

If you're using SSH key, you might not have your keys loaded in the SSH daemon. If you're on a Mac you can do `ssh-add -d` followed by `ssh-add`

Try also SSH'ing directly into the server using the same username, password, and port and pasting what it says.

Comment: Using the [Github tool for mac](http://mac.github.com/) makes it easy to add your github key to your keychain (after which xcode works fine)